# Parse YAML files without writing java classes in prior

Tags: java, parsing, yaml

I want to write a YAML parser in Java which is able to parse different formats of YAML files. Typically, one would analyze the YAML and write respective java classes for mapping them via Jackson. However, I want to have a pluggable architecture and think of an approach which allows to generate adapters for certain YAML schemas. An optimal solution would be to generate the needed java classes directly when reading the YAML.

Is that possible in any way?

Edit:
I re-thought my problem and came to the solution that reading the YAML file and writing it into a hashmap is the most suitable way to work around it without writing static java classes for each format, I want to accept.

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
    .getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("templates/template.yml");
Map<String, Object> templateMap = yaml.load(inputStream);
```

Comment: I found that the problem had a simple solution. I've edited my question with the corresponding code snippet. @flyx's answer helped me a lot in realizing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to write a YAML parser in Java which is able to parse different formats of YAML files.

How would that parser be different to SnakeYAML, the most popular Java YAML parser (which Jackson uses)? I am not saying don't do it, but be aware that your problem possibly has been solved already.

> Typically, one would analyze the YAML and write respective java classes for mapping them via Jackson.

Then whatever you want to write is not a parser. A parser is the component transforming the raw input data into an abstract syntax tree. Jackson is, by the way, an abstraction API above YAML (it also provides JSON and XML support). If you want to process YAML exclusively, it's usually better to use SnakeYAML directly.

> However, I want to have a pluggable architecture and think of an approach which allows to generate adapters for certain YAML schemas.

Have a look at SnakeYAML's API. It allows you to specify a certain class as target for loading a YAML file. This class is basically used as YAML schema for the input. This means that SnakeYAML is a parser that does not know the target schema, but provides means for the user to specify the schema. Is that not exactly what you want?

> An optimal solution would be to generate the needed java classes directly when reading the YAML.

You are reading YAML at runtime. Classes are a tool used at compile time for defining data layout and type hierarchies, facilitating type checking, encapsulation and so on. Usually, it does not make sense to generate classes at runtime.

To sum up: It is rather unclear what exactly you want to do. Maybe try and describe the problem you want to solve with an example. The basic answer to your question is: Yes of course it is possible to write a YAML parser without knowing the target classes; SnakeYAML is the proof.